# How to find an intersection of confidence intervals

Tags: r, probability, confidence-interval, uncertainty

I need to calculate the uncertainty level of the intersection point of two lines given that we know the confidence intervals (CI) for both lines.
Is the intersection of lines CIs would be a corresponding lower and upper intervals of the intersection point? And what is the probability of that CI?

I.e., here is the `r` example.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create random dataset for line A
df <- 
  data.frame(
    x = seq(3, 9, by = .1)
  ) %>%  
  mutate(y = cos(x) + 1)


# Create a function to estimate uncertainties
unc <- function(x){
  
  ume <- rnorm(30,
               mean = 1,
               sd = .05)
  
  sim <- x * ume
  
  quantile(sim, probs = c(.025, .975)) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    rename(val = 2) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rowname,
                values_from = val) %>% 
    rename(lower = 1,
           upper = 2)
  
}

# Calculate CI attributed to measuring errors
set.seed(2021)
df_sim <- df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(sim = map(data, ~unc(.x$y))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data, sim)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Interception line B
int <- 
  data.frame(
    x = df$x,
int_y = rep(1.5, length(df$x)),
    int_lwr = rep(1.45, length(df$x)),
int_upr = rep(1.6, length(df$x))
  )

df_sim %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower,
                  ymax = upper),
              alpha = .4) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = int,
    aes(ymin = int_lwr,
        ymax = int_upr,
        y = int_y,
        x = x),
    alpha = .4,
    fill = "coral"
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = int$int_y[1],
             color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, by = .5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, by = .25)) +
  theme_light()
```

Would it be fair to consider blue circles on the graph as lower and upper CI of the intersection? Where gray ribbon is a 95% CI of the line A and red ribbon is a 95% CI of line B. Would be the intersection CI also a 95%?

[image]

Comment: The gray area could not possibly be a confidence region for the curve: it is some (strange) kind of *prediction* region, perhaps.  This raises questions about what you are trying to do. It would help to describe your problem in English rather than relying on the code to explain what you want to ask.